# Status of Larry Guth's Sponge Problem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, systolic-geometry

[Edited Jan 23, 2021]

Let $D^n$ be the $n$-dimensional unit radius disk in euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Larry Guth's *Sponge Problem* asks: Does there exist a constant $\epsilon=\epsilon_n$ such that every open subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $vol(U)< \epsilon_n$ admits an expanding embedding $f: U\hookrightarrow D^n$?

Recall $f$ is expanding embedding (EE) iff $f$ is a continuous embedding and the symmetric matrix ${}^tDf\cdot Df$ has all eigenvalues $\geq 1$. This last *local condition* holds iff $||D_xf(v)||\geq ||v||$ for every $x\in U$ and tangent vector $v\in T_x U$. Equivalently $f$ is (EE) iff $f$ increases the induced path length of all curves in $U$, where the path length is defined by continuous paths contained in the image $f(U)$.

My previous best estimate $\epsilon_n^*$ for $\epsilon_n$ comes from obvious example of two disks $D_1, D_2$ of radius $1/2$ kissing, which disks $U':=D_1\cup D_2$ cannot be properly expanded embedded into $D$. (The two kissing disks *barely* embed into $D$, even though they occupy only $1/2^{n-1}$ a fraction of the volume of $D^n$). Similar examples arise from "truncated" Apollonian packings, e.g. the first figures of Sarnak's MAA address
http://web.math.princeton.edu/sarnak/InternalApollonianPackings09.pdf

Possible counterexamples arise among low density disk packings which are strongly *jammed*, as investigated by S. Torquato and F.H. Stillinger, e.g. consider the following figures which are reproduced from Figure 2, https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0112319 . In the figure 2 [image]

we see a packing which is rigidly jammed, and which cannot be anywhere locally expanded embedded into a smaller disk (or rectangle in this case).
The construction of such rigidly jammed packings which have arbitrarily small density is described in https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/zkri/220/7/article-p657.xml
For example, consider the figure 2 in Fischer, reproduced below [image]
The rigidity of these packings is a form of incompressibility which can possibly lead to counterexamples to the Sponge Problem.

We emphasize that the packings in the above figures cannot be compressed (contained within a smaller boundary) via a global expanding-embedding. For example, there are no volume preserving rigid motions which preserve tangencies between all the disks, and which compresses the packing into a smaller volume.

**Question**: Can anybody provide further update on the status of L.Guth's Sponge Problem? Are better approximations $\epsilon^*$ known, or candidate open sets $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $vol(U)<\epsilon_n^*$ which cannot be expanded embedded into $D$?

Comment: What is the best upper bound of $\epsilon_n^{*}$?

Comment: Do you mean disks of diameter 1/2 + eps for any eps > 0 (which does yield your bound)? Else for the two kissing disks of diameter 1/2 each, which is contained in D(0, 1), you can bulge parts of one out staying inside D(0, 1), which gives an expanding embedding. Am I missing something?

Comment: If reference disk $D$ has radius $r=1$, then the kissing disks have radius $r_1=r_2=1/2$. The interiors of the kissing disks are disjoint, and can be embedded into $D$, but every arbitrarily small $\epsilon$-thickening of $D_1 \cup D_2$, or pair of kissing disks of radius $r_1=r_2=1/2+\epsilon$ *cannot* be expanded embedded into $D$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Do you know what could be done with annuli? It seems easy to see that an annuli around a circle of radius $r$ of thickness $C(r)$ expanded embeds in $D(0; 1)$ only if $C(r) = O(1/r)$ (one needs to make it very wrinkly), but I'd have to think about the constants.

Comment: Annuli appear to be no different than rectangles (with respect to e-embeddings), but I don't have a precise criterion for which rectangles e-embed into $D$ (except volume and disjoint disks). All this sponge stuff appears to have begun with Ya. Barzdin and A. Kolmogorov. On realization of nets in 3-dimensional space. Problems of
Cybernetics, 19:261–268, 1967. But I have not studied that paper. Some introduction can be found in last chapter of P.G.Adey's thesis https://pgadey.com/ut-thesis.pdf .

Comment: @JHM I was thinking of the following, does this work? Take your example, $D_1 \cup D_2$ where each disk has radius $r_1 = r_2 = 1/2 + \varepsilon$. Now drill a smaller disk $D_3 \subset D_2$ out, and fill the hole $D_3$ in by an Apollonian disk packing by open disks. The pores are so densely populated inside $D_3$ that they don't seem "squishable", and this has clearly less area than your example $D_1 \cup D_2$. Is this the true sponge idea? (Edit: Thanks for those references, by the way!)

Comment: @BalarkaSen Yes!, i think your comment contains a nice improvement of $\epsilon^*$. If we replace any open set $U$ with an Apollonian packing $A$ of itself of *minimal volume*, then $vol(A)<vol(U)$ and $U$ e-embeds into $D$ iff $A$ e-embeds into $D$. So replacing the two kissing disks with an apollonian packing of minimal volume would improve $\epsilon^*$ by some factor.

Comment: Reportedly there exist "rigid/jammed" packings of arbitrarily low density, but the articles are behind degruyter paywall. https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/zkri/221/5-7/article-p563.xml?language=en. If these novel packings N are *incompressible" then maybe $\epsilon^*$ is zero.

Comment: @JHM https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5fthz04z81z8hs/dorozinski2006.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Do you know how to map the following set? Take all rational points on a circle and connect every pair of them by a thin road, in a such way that total area is small.

Comment: @ArseniyAkopyan No, I don't know how. But would such an open set be any different from the disk? (If I connected them by roads, my roads would fill the disk). Do you have an image/picture of what your roads would look like?

Comment: @JHM, the total area of the roads might be arbitrary small.

Comment: I think the stable packings constructed by Werner Fischer (see the above figures) are effectively counter examples to Guth's Sponge Problem. Stable packings do not have any strictly local deformations -- if any sphere is moved, it is moved by a global deformation. And this prevents any expanding embedding from deforming the packing into a smaller domain.

Answer (score 1):

If one removes the injectivity condition, then the answer is "yes".
(At least in the two-dimensional case.)
That is, there is a lengh-increasding immersion $U\looparrowright D$.

Indeed, note that $U$ can be sliced by line segments from-boundary-to-boundary into subsets of diameter $100\cdot\sqrt{\varepsilon}$.
Arrange these pieces near the center of $D$.
Connect the corresponding cuts by immersed road in $D$ of the same width.
Finally, note that we can spread a neighborhood of each cut along the road in a length-increasing way.

Comment: Preferably any proof of Sponge Problem would make no appeals to width-volume inequalities (since Guth's motivation for Sponge Problem was to find new independant proof of Gromov's width-volume inequalities). I should have made this clear in the question. Do you know of elementary proof that $U$ can be partitioned into relative cycles of diameter $<100 \sqrt{\epsilon}$ (or $100^{100^{100}}\sqrt{\epsilon}$) in dimension two?

Comment: @IHM it follows from Besicovitch, is not it?

Comment: If it follows from Besicovitch (eg. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.10040) then i dont see how, especially if $U$ is an open subset of small volume (possibly countably infinite genus in two dimensions).

Comment: @JHM you can always assume that it is bounded by a finite number of smooth closed curves.

Comment: The above immersion is strictly *locally* length increasing, or am I mistaken? (where distance on the image is induced path length as a subset of $D$). My definition of expanding-embedding is incomplete: it needs hypothesis that $f$ is *injective*. And is it clear that your map is continuous? Namely, when you "arrange these pieces" and when you "connect the corresponding cuts..." how to ensure a *continuous map* is being defined? It's interesting that the volume of the image $f(U)\subset D$ can perhaps(!) be made arbitrarily small by your construction, an "expanding collapse".

Comment: @JHM no, you cannot make volume arbitrary small -- it is impossible to find an immersion of a round disc into a smaller disc. About continuity -- it should be clear, my explanation is vague (make sure you see the meaning of "roads"). By the way no need to use Besicovitch; one can assume that the set is polygonal, take a sufficiently dense subset of its boundary and pass to its Delaunay triangulation.

Comment: Of course the round disk *is* diffeomorphic to smaller disks in $\mathbb{R}^n$. And immersions are identical with local diffeos and submersions because we are studying maps between *open* subsets in finite dimensions. Even Alexander trick suffices to rescale the entire space, and immerse/diffeo/submerse the image $f(U)$ into arbitrarily small ball. What is impossible is to find a locally expanding injective immersion (i.e. locally expanding diffeomorphism) of the round disk to a smaller disk. Is that what you meant?

Comment: If the immersion is non injective, then I think it's quite plausible the volume of the image can decrease, even if the immersion is locally expanding. And to be specific, by "volume of the image" i mean the unit-normalized Lebesgue volume of the set-theoretic image $f(U)$.

Comment: @JHM it seems that you forget about length-increasing property.

Comment: i forgot that immersions between equidimensional disks are diffeos. So yes, you are correct that there do not exist expanding diffeos from a disk to smallet disks.